# Return a DataTable from a WebMethod function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

This is my code :

Server :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetAll()
    {
       NotificationForSupport NFS = new NotificationForSupport();
        string s = NFS.GetData();
        return s;
    }
```

ClientSide :

```
      function getData() {

        var $msg = $('#msg');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetAll',
            data: '{ }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $msg.html(data.d);

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");

            }
        });
    }
```

as you can see my function return a string but now i want it to return a dataTable instead of that string i know how should i make my server side fnct return a string but how can i handle to read that DataTable in the client side from my ajax

Comment: You can also return a `JSON` object...

Comment: what do you mean can you provide an example

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. Read more about it. It could be useful to you in the future...

Comment: You cannot return datatable. it is not serializable. You can either return dataset or convert datatable to JSON object.

Comment: @Osa E - DataTable : ISerializable